# Delphi - dbGrid Select All

Tags: delphi, checkbox, delphi-7, dbgrid

I put on a TwwdbGrid a checkbox field to select the record, I'd like to know if it's possible to put a checkbox on the label of the field on the grid and when the user click on it, it's select all the fields, anyone knows how to do that???

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing it is to use a **TImageList** and override **DoCalcTitleImage**.  Heres a stripped down version where I have subclassed the grid and added support for various images on the columns.

```
procedure TRGDBGrid.DoCalcTitleImage(Sender: TObject; Field: TField;
  var TitleImageAttributes: TwwTitleImageAttributes);

begin
  inherited;
  { Get Image Number }
  lAttr := Attribute_Of_Field;
  TitleImageAttributes.ImageIndex := ord(lAttr);
end;
```

You can use two images - an unchecked and a check checkbox.  And you need to use **OnTitleClick** event to handle it.

Comment: If that answers your question then you should tick it.